# Why I can't get the offset of a DIV using JSDOM?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, jsdom

This is what I'm doing:

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
mocha.describe('div', function() {
  mocha.it('positions', function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<div style="left:55px;position:absolute;" id="d">x</div>'
    var div = document.getElementById('d');
    var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log('Left: ' + rect.left);
  }
}
```

I get this:

```
Left: 0
```

It is supposed to be 55, isn't it? I'm using jsdom/16.2.2, jsdom-global/3.0.2, mocha/6.1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsdom does not implement a layout engine (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1322), so it cannot compute any offsets.

Answer (score 0):

According sources of [getBoundingClientRect method](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/09301dadab36fe2d71a95029adfbc9e9fe18854c/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Element-impl.js#L353) it's a stub only. Other words this method does not do any calculations.